# Subgroups of a Finite Group containing two elements

Tags: group-theory

Currently working on a Group Theory question:

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order 100 and let $a \in G$ denote a generator.
Find two subgroups of $G$ which contain both $a^{20}$ and $a^{55}$.
Are there any other subgroups of $G$ containing these two elements?

So my attempt at this question is taking the given. The order of $G$ is 100 and I know that $a^m = n/gcd(m,n)$. But I'm unsure as to how this helps.  Any hints on how to proceed are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: fill in details.

Observe that

$$ord(a^{20})=5\;,\;\;ord(a^{55})=20\;\implies\;\text{any subgroup containing this two elements will}$$

have at least order $\;20\;$ ....but also  order $\;20\;$ **at most** (why? Lagrange theorem), and since any finite *cyclic* group has one **unique** proper subgroup of any order dividing the group's order then there is only one such subgroup

Comment: I think that there are at least two: yours and $G$ itself.

Comment: @Antoine Thanks, edited...though I believe the intention was "proper subgroup".

Comment: @DonAntonio I have not touched Lagrange Theorem yet.  But to be clear, the only two subgroups that contain both of these elements is a subgroup or order 20 and G itself. I think G is an answer in this case since there was no indication of "proper subgroup"

Comment: @ElSpiffy Both groups, $\;G\;$ itself and the subgroup generated by $\;a^{55}\;$ , are indeed the answer.